# Number of Integers using Inclusion-Exclusion

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $p_1 , p_2 , ... , p_k$ be distinct primes.

How can I show in general that the amount of integers that are not divisible by any $p_i$ is

$$n - \sum_{1 \leq i \leq k} \lfloor \frac{n}{p_i} \rfloor + \sum_{1 \leq i, j \leq k} \lfloor \frac{n}{p_{i}p_{j}} \rfloor - ... + (-1)^{k} \lfloor \frac{n}{p_{1}p_{2}...p_{k}} \rfloor $$

For example, from 1 to 100, there are $100 - (50+33+20) + (16+10+6) - 3 = 26$ integers that are not divisible by 2, 3 or 5.

Can anyone check my progress please?

This is my current progress.

Let $A_{i}$ be the set of integers from 1 to n that are divisible by $p_{i}$.

Then by PIE,
The amount of integers indivisible by any p is
$n - \sum |A_i| + \sum |A_{i} \cap A_{j}| - ... + (-1)^k |A_{1} \cap A_{2} \cap ... \cap A_{k}|$
Then I'm lost here.

Comment: I am confused.  All of your analysis seems correct to me.  Letting $A_i$ denote the set of elements that are divisible by $p_i$, clearly $\displaystyle |A_i| = \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p_i}\right\rfloor.$  The rest of the analysis (e.g. $|A_i \cap A_j|$) is similar.

Comment: @user2661923 So, am I got it yet? Or do I have to state more?

Comment: By the way, for what it's worth, the use of the floor function is actually unnecessary.  That is, as defined, $n$ is a multiple of the product of any combination of the factors, $p_i, p_j, \cdots $.

Comment: @user2661923  I got it. The first statement is wrong, I'll edit it. Thamk you.

Comment: In my opinion, your analysis, coupled with my comments, provides a complete answer.  If this is a homework problem, then I advise including my comments, in your own words in your answer.  You might also include the following link [Inclusion Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: @user2661923 thank you so much sir

Comment: @user2661923  The use of the floor function is needed to ensure that the result is an integer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Nice catch.  I **misread** the question as specifying that $n = (p_1 \times p_2 \times \cdots \times p_k).$

Answer (score 1):

You are very close, since you the PIE expression you have looks almost exactly like the alternating sum of fractions you want. To complete the proof, you only need to explain why it is true that$$|A_{i(1)}\cap \dots \cap A_{i(k)}|=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p_{i(1)}\cdots p_{i(k)}}\right\rfloor,$$
for any $\{i(1),\dots,i(k)\}\subseteq \{1\dots,k\}$. There are two pieces two this puzzle:

- Argue why $A_{i(1)}\cap \dots \cap A_{i(k)}$, the set of integers divisible by each of $p_{i(1)},\dots,p_{i(k)}$, is also equal to the set of integers divisible by the product $p_{i(1)}\times \dots \times p_{i(k)}$. This is a number theory principle, which is easiest seen by considering prime factorizations. If $p$ and $q$ are primes which are both factors of some integer $s$, then the product $pq$ is also a factor of $s$.
- Argue why, for any $m$, the number of integers in $\{1,\dots,n\}$ which are multiples of $m$ is $\lfloor n/m\rfloor$. This is is not too hard to see if you look at some examples. Basically, the multiples of $m$ in the range $\{1,\dots,n\}$ are of the form $m\cdot r$, where $r$ must satisfy $m\cdot r\le n$, or $r\le n/m$. Since $r$ is a positive integer less than or equal to $n/m$, the number for choices for $r$ is the largest integer less than or equal to $n/m$, which by definition is $\lfloor n/m\rfloor$.